# Conda install pip failure

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install anaconda to my Alienware 17, so I downloaded the installer and executed (Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64).

Then, I opened anaconda prompt using "run as administrator". And I typed

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install pip
```

Then it printed following message:

```
WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
Collecting package metadata: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Then it created long list of errors. In short,

```
environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
        CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
                CONDA_EXE=C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe
               CONDA_EXES="C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts\conda.exe"
             CONDA_PREFIX=C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3
    CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
               CONDA_ROOT=C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=1
                CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0
                 HOMEPATH=\Users\sonic
          NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
                     PATH=C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\condabin\..;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\condabin
                          \..\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Library
                          \usr\bin;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Library\bin;C:\Users\son
                          ic\Anaconda3\condabin\..\Scripts;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\condabin\..\
                          bin;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w6
                          4\bin;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda
                          3\Library\bin;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda
                          3\bin;C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files
                          (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
                          Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
                          Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CU
                          DA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
                          Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\Sys
                          tem32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
                          Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WIN
                          DOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1
                          .0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS
                          \System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;E:\Open
                          F;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
                          Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA
                          NvDLISR;D:\Program Files\OpenBabel-2.4.1;C:\Users\sonic\AppData\Local\
                          Microsoft\WindowsApps
             PSMODULEPATH=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\Windows
                          PowerShell\v1.0\Modules
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\sonic\.condarc
 populated config files :
          conda version : 4.6.11
    conda-build version : 3.17.8
         python version : 3.7.3.final.0
       base environment : C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\sonic\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\sonic\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\Users\sonic\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\sonic\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\sonic\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.11 requests/2.21.0 CPython/3.7.3 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
```

I really don't know what to do. Run as administrator or not, but both created the same error.I also tried conda activate, but didn't helped. I also tried:

```
conda update conda
```

but this command also created the crash with similar error list.

May I ask what is the issue here? I'm really not sure what to do anymore at this point... Should I need to install something before Anaconda?

Thanks

Comment: Don't run or install Conda (Miniconda or Anaconda) as admin. It's designed to not required elevated privileges.

Comment: @merv I tried the same thing, not as an administrator, but still the same error occur.

Comment: Is the "error report" only including what you've shown (basically `conda info`)? Right now it doesn't even say what the error type is. Definitely try to upgrade Conda, 4.6.11 is known to have Windows-specific bugs.  Does `conda install -n base conda=4.6.14` work?

Comment: @merv Well I solved this in other way: I installed in other machine I have. Thank you anyway.